# How can I change the newline code for fish shell

Tags: bash, fish, cmder, omf

I'm using windows 10 and installed cmder, using the fish shell with omf Theme fishface.
But every new row, it will show a new row Mark as this picture. [Screenshot for new row mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJsb7.png)

How can I get rid of this mark?

** didn't work if I change to another theme too.

---

Additional information without cmder.

[Screenshot with cmd.exe + bash + fish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX3K9.png)

Comment: Has this been resolved in cmder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable that feature. The fish shell uses a heuristic (inherited from zsh) to determine if the output of the preceding command ended with a newline. If it doesn't it displays the Unicode U+23CE symbol (what you're seeing) or a tilde. Search the code for the symbol `PROMPT_SP`. Commit 58347d49 that I wrote and merged 2016-12-23 fixed that behavior for the Windows ConEmu terminal emulator. See [issue 789](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/789). Based on your problem description it appears that heuristic does not work correctly in the `cmder` terminal. This probably means that terminal emulator has a bug since it doesn't behave like nearly all the terminals that fish runs on. Feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new)